# Find the Limit of the sequence $\frac{(2^n)(n!)}{(2n+1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, factorial

Find the Limit of the sequence $\frac{(2^n)(n!)}{(2n+1)!}$

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I tried the squeeze method, but could not figure it out.

Comment: It looks like the limit would be zero since only the even terms are cancelled from the denominator, and that uses up the entire numerator...

Comment: To put @abiessu's pertinent observation slightly differently, the numerator divides the denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note
$$2^n\cdot n! = (2 \times \cdots \times 2) \times (n \times \cdots \times 1) = (2n) \times (2(n - 1)) \times \cdots \times 2.$$
Therefore
$$\frac{2^n\cdot n!}{(2n + 1)!} = \frac{(2n) \times (2(n - 1)) \times \cdots \times 2}{(2n + 1) \times (2n) \times \cdots \times 1} = \frac{1}{(2n + 1)\times(2n - 1)\times\cdots\times 3 \times 1} \to 0$$
as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: That's pretty cool. I was just a bit confused by the notation, but I'm not that familiar with formal Math.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$
a_n = \frac{2^nn!}{(2n+1)!}
$$

So then we have

$$
a_n = \frac{2^nn!}{(2n+1)!} , a_{n+1} = \frac{2^{n+1}(n+1)!}{(2{(n+1)}+1)!} 
= \frac{2^{n+1}(n!)(n+1)}{(2n+3)!}
$$

Taking the ratio test, $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$

$$
\frac{\frac{2^nn!}{(2n+1)!}}{\frac{2^{n+1}(n!)(n+1)}{(2n+3)!}}=\frac{2^n(n!)(2n+3)!}{2^{n+1}(2n+1)!(n!)(n+1)}
=\frac{(2n+3)(2n+2)}{2(n+1)}
=\frac{(2n+3)(2n+2)}{2n+2} = 2n+3
$$

So taking the limit:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 2n+3 \rightarrow \infty
$$

So the series converges. ($a_{n+1}$ becomes smaller and smaller compared to the preceding term.)

Answer (score 1):

Our guess for the limit of the sequence is $0$.

Consider the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2^n)(n!)}{(2n+1)!}$$

Apply the ratio test:

$$\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| = \frac{ \frac{(2^{n+1})(n+1)!}{(2n+3)!} }{ \frac{(2^n)(n!)}{(2n+1)!} }= \frac{2(n+1)}{(2n+3)(2n+2)}$$

Then,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2(n+1)}{(2n+3)(2n+2)} = 0 < 1$$

Hence, the series converges.

A series $\sum a_n$ is convergent $\implies$ $\lim a_n = 0$

Answer (score 0):

Moving to the n+1 term from this

$\frac{(2^n)(n!)}{(2n+1)!}$

You multiply by $\frac{2(n+1)}{(2n+2)(2n+3)}$ which result multiplication by:

$\frac{1}{2n+3}$

So the sequence converges to 0